# SVG: Export for mophing Animation

Tags: javascript, html, css, svg, adobe-illustrator

When I create a SVG Path in Illustrator and change the position of the points for a morphing animation the points are totally different!

For example:

```
<path d="M 355.077,300c-31.017,0-31.017-200-62.034-200 s-31.017,200-62.034,200c-31.015,0-31.015-200-62.031-200c-31.014,0-31.014,200-62.029,200c-31.013,0-31.013-200-62.026-200"/>
```

and

```
 <path d="M355.077,217.635 c-31.017,0-31.017-64.507-62.034-64.507s-31.017,185.701-62.034,185.701c-31.015,0-31.015-274.316-62.031-274.316 c-31.014,0-31.014,175.276-62.029,175.276c-31.013,0-31.013-97.737-62.026-97.737"/>
```

are the same path (with moved points obviously). However, the order in which they occur is totally different and therefore the animation pushes the points all around the SVG element.

I have tried all export scripts Illustrator offers.

Is there a trick for getting a consistent result when exporting? So that the points are at the right place? Perhaps a plug-in I can use?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

**This is not an answer**. This is just to say that the paths can be used for morphing since the commands and the number of the commands is the same. However if the paths you have are different a solution would be to change all the commands to `C`

```html
<svg viewBox="0 0 400 400" width="300">

<path fill="gold" d="M 355.077,300
                     c-31.017,0-31.017-200-62.034-200 
                     s-31.017,200-62.034,200
                     c-31.015,0-31.015-200-62.031-200
                     c-31.014,0-31.014,200-62.029,200
                     c-31.013,0-31.013-200-62.026-200">
  
  <animate 
       attributeName="d"
       attributeType="XML"
       values="M 355.077,300
                     c-31.017,0-31.017-200-62.034-200 
                     s-31.017,200-62.034,200
                     c-31.015,0-31.015-200-62.031-200
                     c-31.014,0-31.014,200-62.029,200
                     c-31.013,0-31.013-200-62.026-200;
               M355.077,217.635 
         c-31.017,0-31.017-64.507-62.034-64.507
         s-31.017,185.701-62.034,185.701
         c-31.015,0-31.015-274.316-62.031-274.316 
         c-31.014,0-31.014,175.276-62.029,175.276
         c-31.013,0-31.013-97.737-62.026-97.737;
               
               M 355.077,300
                     c-31.017,0-31.017-200-62.034-200 
                     s-31.017,200-62.034,200
                     c-31.015,0-31.015-200-62.031-200
                     c-31.014,0-31.014,200-62.029,200
                     c-31.013,0-31.013-200-62.026-200"
       dur="5s"
       repeatCount="indefinite"/>
  </path>


  
</svg>
```

Comment: Thanks, this is very helpful! I will try out a converter and see if it works with all commands set to "c".